# How do we go from Exp distribution to Gamma distribution?

Tags: distributions

I was reading a proof on a paper online and he said that the exponential is a special case of the Gamma distribution, how's that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really a lazy question, you can get your answer easily by doing a simple search on google.

Anyway, the Exponetial distribution is related to a lot of other distributions: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution#Related_distributions

Comment: This should be a comment, link-only answers are frowned upon.

Comment: @JuhoKokkala I'm sorry, I didn't know that.